# Changing the icon of a JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

So I am trying to create a tic tac toe game that uses the possible slots as buttons. At the start of the game, the buttons are set to a blank white image as their icon. When the button is clicked I am trying to have the button icon change to the corresponding image (x or o), however when a button is clicked the image does not change? Where am I going wrong?

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants  ;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

private static final String TITLE = "Tic Tac Toe";
private static final int width = 600;
private static final int height = 800;

private Container content;
private JButton exitbutton;
private JButton initbutton;
private JButton[] spaces = new JButton[9];
private CellButtonHandler[] cellHandler = new CellButtonHandler[9];
private InitButtonHandler inithandler;
private ExitButtonHandler exithandler;
private JLabel turn;
private URL base;
private Image o, x, blank;
private Font myfont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 78);
private ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("data/blankButton.png");
private ImageIcon iconx = new ImageIcon("data/x.png");
private ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon("data/o.gif");

private boolean gameover;
private boolean turnX;

public TicTacToe() {
    setTitle(TITLE);
    setSize(width, height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    content = getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.black);

    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));

    for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
        spaces[i] = new JButton();
        cellHandler[i] = new CellButtonHandler();
        spaces[i].addActionListener(cellHandler[i]);
    }

    exitbutton = new JButton("Exit");
    exithandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitbutton.addActionListener(exithandler);
    initbutton = new JButton("Clear");
    inithandler = new InitButtonHandler();
    initbutton.addActionListener(inithandler);

    turn = new JLabel("X's turn", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    turn.setForeground(Color.white);

    for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
        spaces[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        content.add(spaces[i]);
    }

    content.add(initbutton);
    content.add(turn);
    content.add(exitbutton);

    init();
}

public void init() {
    turnX = true;
    gameover = false;
    spaces[0].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[1].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[2].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[3].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[4].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[5].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[6].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[7].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[8].setIcon(icon);

    turn.setText("X's turn");

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
}

private class CellButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (gameover) {
            return;
        }

        JButton pressed = (JButton) (e.getSource());

        if (pressed.getIcon().equals(icono) || pressed.getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
            return;
        }

        if (turnX) {
            pressed.setIcon(iconx);
        } else {
            pressed.setIcon(icono);
        }

        if (checkwinnerO()) {
            gameover = true;
            turn.setText("O Wins!");
            } 

        if(checkwinnerX()){
            gameover = true;
            turn.setText("X Wins!");
        }
    }
}

private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private class InitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        init();
    }
}

public boolean checkwinnerO() {
    if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[1].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[2].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[3].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[6].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[3].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[1].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else 

        return false;
}

public boolean checkwinnerX() {
    if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[1].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[2].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[3].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[6].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[3].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[1].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else 

        return false;

}
}
```

1. The image icons are initialized.
2. My `init` method sets each of the buttons icon to the blank image.
3. My `CellHandlerMethod` handles the change between the blank image and the image (x or o) when clicked.

Comment: Are you using a debugger to step through the code to see what is being executed when you click the button? If you don't use a debugger did you add any System.out.println(...) statements to track the execution in your ActionListener? I see return statements in your code, are they being executed? Also, there is no need to create a different ActionListener for each button. You can create one listener and add the listener to each button.

Comment: Where are the images stroked? Are the stored with the programs jar file or externally on the file system?

Comment: you may need to use repaint() on your frame

Comment: @SnoopDogg, not when you use the setIcon() method. Swing components are smart enough to invoke revalidate() and repaint() when you change a property of the component that affects the way it should be painted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This output definitely shows a problem with the logic of the game.

[image: Tic Tac Toe]

Note that it **does** change from the red square (representing 'blank') to the green circle when the button(s) is(/are) clicked.  But it never flips from Player X to Player Y (or vice-versa).

As to why you are not seeing ***any*** change, I can only conclude one of 3 things:

1. The images are not where you think they are.
2. The images are not named what you think they are.  (E.G. `x.png != X.png || x.PNG`)
3. The images are not using an internal format understood by Java.  Try displaying them directly in a `JOptionPane`.

### Tips

Don't use an `ImageIcon` to load an image, it does not give feedback.  Instead use `ImageIO.read(..)` which provides lots of helpful feedback.

### Source

This is the slightly altered source used.  It hot-links to 3 images (so that users of the code can see it work or fail).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

private static final String TITLE = "Tic Tac Toe";
private static final int width = 600;
private static final int height = 800;

private Container content;
private JButton exitbutton;
private JButton initbutton;
private JButton[] spaces = new JButton[9];
private CellButtonHandler[] cellHandler = new CellButtonHandler[9];
private InitButtonHandler inithandler;
private ExitButtonHandler exithandler;
private JLabel turn;
private URL base;
private Image o, x, blank;
private Font myfont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 78);
private ImageIcon icon;
private ImageIcon iconx;
private ImageIcon icono;

private boolean gameover;
private boolean turnX;

public TicTacToe() {
    setTitle(TITLE);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0JHK.png");
        icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        URL urlx = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png");
        iconx = new ImageIcon(urlx);
        URL urlo = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoKxT.png");
        icono = new ImageIcon(urlo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setSize(width, height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    content = getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.black);

    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));

    for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
        spaces[i] = new JButton();
        cellHandler[i] = new CellButtonHandler();
        spaces[i].addActionListener(cellHandler[i]);
    }

    exitbutton = new JButton("Exit");
    exithandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitbutton.addActionListener(exithandler);
    initbutton = new JButton("Clear");
    inithandler = new InitButtonHandler();
    initbutton.addActionListener(inithandler);

    turn = new JLabel("X's turn", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    turn.setForeground(Color.white);

    for (int i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
        spaces[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        content.add(spaces[i]);
    }

    content.add(initbutton);
    content.add(turn);
    content.add(exitbutton);

    init();
}

public void init() {
    turnX = true;
    gameover = false;
    spaces[0].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[1].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[2].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[3].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[4].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[5].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[6].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[7].setIcon(icon);
    spaces[8].setIcon(icon);

    turn.setText("X's turn");

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
}

private class CellButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (gameover) {
            return;
        }

        JButton pressed = (JButton) (e.getSource());

        if (pressed.getIcon().equals(icono) || pressed.getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
            return;
        }

        if (turnX) {
            pressed.setIcon(iconx);
        } else {
            pressed.setIcon(icono);
        }

        if (checkwinnerO()) {
            gameover = true;
            turn.setText("O Wins!");
            }

        if(checkwinnerX()){
            gameover = true;
            turn.setText("X Wins!");
        }
    }
}

private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private class InitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        init();
    }
}

public boolean checkwinnerO() {
    if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[1].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[2].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[3].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[6].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[3].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[1].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(icono)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(icono) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(icono)) {
        return true;
    } else

        return false;
}

public boolean checkwinnerX() {
    if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[1].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[2].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[3].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[6].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[3].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[1].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[7].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[5].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[0].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[8].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else if (spaces[2].getIcon().equals(iconx)
            && spaces[4].getIcon().equals(iconx) && spaces[6].getIcon().equals(iconx)) {
        return true;
    } else

        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I figured out the reason my images were not working is because I was trying to load it like you would an applet(Up to this point most of the games I have made use applets). Using ImageIO.read(..)  does fix this problem. Thanks again

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the error with my logic regarding player turns.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I tried using URL base to get to my src folder when using applets and that was one of the things that i tried(and obviously failed) doing. And yes i did not use ImageOP.read() to fix my problem, i created another program to try this method and it worked. I was able to get my game to work by fixing where my game was getting the image source.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)